# Combination of e-mail body & signature in mailtoURL link

Tags: email, url, outlook, mailto, email-signature

I got a problem concerning building mailtoURL links - unfortunately i can't manage to combine the signature and the subject.

I want to create a link to a new e-mail with pre-filled Mail-subject, recipient & mail-text.
After i´ve created a shortcut in JIRA-Software the content of the e-mail doesn´t look like expected.

**Code:**

```
mailto:test@test.de?subject=JIRA%20Software%20-%20Störungsmeldung&body=Das%20ist%20ein%20Test
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
mailto:test@test.de?subject=JIRA%20Software%20-%20Störungsmeldung&amp;body=Das%20ist%20ein%20Test
```

**Result:**
Mail with signature, but without e-mail body.

How can i combine the signature & body? (`&amp;` doesn´t do the job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mailtol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol doesn't provide anything for the signature specifically. The best what you could do is to include it to the text to appear in the body of the message (plain text).

Comment: Thanks for your message. Do you know any alternative workflow?

Comment: You can use any API from your web site such as Graph API (from the backend side) for sending emails.